# How to get only additional logs in AWS CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-cloudwatch

I installed CloudWatch Agent to my VM(WSL) by following [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/installing-cloudwatch-agent-commandline.html) to monitor logs on VM.
And it seems work properly to show un-updated logs.

But once the log on VM has updated, all rows in the monitored log is added to console of CloudWatch.
For instance, if I add row2 on the log which had already contained row1, row1 is going to be added again with row2.
[here is the screenshot of console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3V5UJ.png)

**/var/log/test-cloudwatch/test.log**

```
[2023-04-25 19:53:16]row1
[2023-04-26 18:21:24]row2
```

**config.json**

```
{
        "agent": {
                "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
                "run_as_user": "root"
        },
        "logs": {
                "logs_collected": {
                        "files": {
                                "collect_list": [
                                        {
                                                "file_path": "/var/log/test-cloudwatch/*.log",
                                                "log_group_name": "log_group_duplicate",
                                                "log_stream_name": "stream_duplicate",
                                                "retention_in_days": 3,
                                                "timestamp_format": "[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]",
                                                "multi_line_start_pattern": "{timestamp_format}"
                                        }
                                ]
                        }
                }
        },
        "metrics": {
                "metrics_collected": {
                        "collectd": {
                                "metrics_aggregation_interval": 60
                        },
                        "cpu": {
                                "measurement": [
                                        "cpu_usage_idle",
                                        "cpu_usage_iowait",
                                        "cpu_usage_steal",
                                        "cpu_usage_guest",
                                        "cpu_usage_user",
                                        "cpu_usage_system"
                                ],
                                "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
                                "totalcpu": true
                        },
                        "disk": {
                                "measurement": [
                                        "used_percent"
                                ],
                                "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
                                "resources": [
                                        "*"
                                ]
                        },
                        "diskio": {
                                "measurement": [
                                        "io_time",
                                        "write_bytes",
                                        "read_bytes",
                                        "writes",
                                        "reads"
                                ],
                                "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
                                "resources": [
                                        "*"
                                ]
                        },
                        "mem": {
                                "measurement": [
                                        "mem_used_percent"
                                ],
                                "metrics_collection_interval": 60
                        },
                        "net": {
                                "measurement": [
                                        "bytes_sent",
                                        "bytes_recv",
                                        "packets_sent",
                                        "packets_recv"
                                ],
                                "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
                                "resources": [
                                        "*"
                                ]
                        },
                        "netstat": {
                                "measurement": [
                                        "tcp_established",
                                        "tcp_time_wait"
                                ],
                                "metrics_collection_interval": 60
                        },
                        "swap": {
                                "measurement": [
                                        "swap_used_percent"
                                ],
                                "metrics_collection_interval": 60
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: it is not re-added, the file is "streamed" to CloudWatch meaning whatever is in the file you pick with cw agent will also be shown in the Log group.